# Column width issue when displaying table of data in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm attempting to display a table of data which looks like this on Windows Phone 7 (thus I don't have the DataGrid control:

```
(The columns are: Rank, Score, Win-Loss, Name.)

7 43 22-7 Aaron
2 13  4-7 Beth
5 42  3-1 Clark
```

And so on.  I have used a ListBox with an ItemTemplate to query the values and print them out, with a Grid to format the list.  However, each grid entry is separate!  I want the columns to all line up, but when an element size is not the same size, it isn't aligned.

This is the code I am using:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding AllPlayers}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="{Binding Rank}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="{Binding Score}"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0,10,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Wins}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="-"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Losses}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Is there a better way to do this?  I could set the pixel width on the "Grid" column manually, but I'd rather have it auto-figure out the width, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WP7 supports one fixed screen pixel width, you can set exact width for each column. What width to use - that's up to you, depending on the content, but that would be the way to keep them all one size.

Comment: Ah I should have clarified.  I can do it that way, but I rather like the "Auto" column size that figures out the width on the fly.  I suppose I should just not be lazy and figure out the max pixel width.  =)

Comment: When it's set to Auto, you will ultimately give up on the ability to limit the width. But hey, there is also `MaxWidth` there!